# Newsletter for Biblical Hermeneutics

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed

I'm having trouble subscribing to the newsletter for this stack exchange site - is it unavailable till the site is public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Biblical Hermeneutics newsletter is available and good to go now!

As always, you can subscribe via any of the following:

- your user-edit page
- the [Stack Exchange newsletters](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters) page
- a newsletter ad in the sidebar

Comment: Yay, Emmett!  Thanks!

Comment: WOOT! Thank you! I appreciate this a a lot! :)